# Trying to make a reuseable DataGrid component with my own defaults from ReactDataGrid, but Typescript giving me errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-data-grid

I'm trying to use [ReactDataGrid](https://reactdatagrid.io) library in TypeScript to create a base `<BaseDataGrid />` component with my own defaults so I can stop repeating myself when using `<ReactDataGrid />` in other pages and other components. Here's my base component:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDataGrid from "@inovua/reactdatagrid-enterprise";
import { TypeDataGridProps } from "@inovua/reactdatagrid-community/types";

const BaseDataGrid = ({
    columns = [],
    dataSource = [],
    rtl = true,
    nativeScroll = true,
    showZebraRows = false,
    checkboxOnlyRowSelect = true,
    rowHeight = 60,
    showColumnMenuTool = false,
    sortable = false,
    ...otherProps
}: TypeDataGridProps) => (
    <ReactDataGrid
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={dataSource}
        className='h-full'
        rtl={rtl}
        nativeScroll={nativeScroll}
        showZebraRows={showZebraRows}
        checkboxOnlyRowSelect={checkboxOnlyRowSelect}
        showColumnMenuTool={showColumnMenuTool}
        sortable={sortable}
        rowHeight={rowHeight}
        {...otherProps}
    />
);

export default BaseDataGrid;
```

But when I'm trying to use it I get this error from TypeScript:

```
Type '{ columns: TypeColumns; dataSource: any[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'TypeDataGridPropsNoI18n': isBinaryOperator, sortFunctions, editStartEvent, clearNodeCacheOnDataSourceChange, and 58 more
```

Here's an example of how I'm trying to use it:

```
import React  from "react";
import BaseDataGrid from "../../../../components/Common/BaseDataGrid";


const Test = () => {
    return (
        <div className='w-full h-96 lg:flex-grow'>
            <BaseDataGrid columns={[]} dataSource={[]} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Test;
```

And here is also a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-faraday-mw1rp?file=/src/App.tsx

Why is it not working when I'm trying to make it as a separate component, but it does work when I import it from library? How can I make a reusable component with my own defaults so that I can pass my own props to it and also keep the component flexible?

I know that the error says I'm missing some default props, but is it logical to type out all of the default props from the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this type signature

```
const BaseDataGrid = ({ .. }: TypeDataGridProps) => ( .. )
```

you're specifying that all the `TypeDataGridProps` props are required, even though you specify default values for all of them. You can use `Partial` to explicitly declare the props as optional:

```
const BaseDataGrid = ({ .. }: Partial<TypeDataGridProps>) => ( .. )
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means you haven't defined values for other required props but are passing them to the component. The props for `BaseDataGrid` are of type `TypeDataGridProps` which has a lot of other properties. Try changing the prop type to `any` and see if it works